# Jenkins Build Queue Limit

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I've noticed that there seems to be a build queue limit of one in Jenkins. When I trigger a lot of builds it seems to only place a max of one build in the build queue. Is there a way to remove this limit so there can be more then one build in the build queue?

Comment: Do you mean building the same job multiple times? Also what's your Jenkins setup? Are you using Docker as slaves?

Comment: @Fadi Yeah so currently I have 4 Build Executors. If I manually build the project 5 times right back to back quickly. It uses 4 Build Executors and puts 1 build into the queue. But if I build the project 6 times instead of 5 it still only puts 1 build into the queue instead of 2 like it should.

Comment: I wonder if it's related to this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-2483?focusedCommentId=127046&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-127046

Comment: Also, it would be better for the rest of us to try to help if you provide more information about your Jenkins setup.. :)

Comment: Oh looks like it might be related to that. That might be the problem. What other information would be helpful?

Comment: Maybe this might have a bit more information: http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Build-queue-length-tp3812929p3825027.html

Comment: Try to have like 6 totally different jobs with different parameters (if possible) running at the same time (and make sure they take a while to build [like maybe put sleep 100, or something]) and see if it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is **intended behaviour**:

- Normally, your jobs will depend on some input (from SCM, or from some upstream jobs)
- If your slave capacity is too low to catch up with each and every build, then you'd normally want to test/build/... only the very latest "item".

This is the default behaviour. Without that, there'd be a risk that the build queue grows indefinitely.

On top of that, Jenkins does not track the properties of normal build requests -- they all look the same, and Jenkins can not (for example) separate different SCM states that existed at different triggering times.

This is however exactly the point that gives you a **workaround**: **parameterize your jobs**, and then use for example the **Trigger parameterized build on other projects** post-build action to trigger those. Then Jenkins will queue each build request individually -- and inside your job, you can use the parameter to find out what exactly has to be done.

Jenkins *will* squash queued parameterized builds that  have *identical* parameter values (thanks to user "atline" for checking).

Comment: Jenkins really check parameters, only with different parameter's value will the new task could be seen in queue.