# Jenkins webhook payload overwritten by next trigger

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, webhooks

We have a pipeline heavily parameterised which is invoked by a webhook from multiple Bitbucket repositories.
This job is setup not to allow concurrent builds.

It works perfectly fine one job at time. Or with one job running + 1 in the queue.

However, when a 3rd job is triggered Jenkins will overwrite the payload contents of the job waiting in the queue with the payload of the newly arrived one.

Let's say:

- Job from developer A is running
- Job from developer B is waiting
- Developer C pushes to Bitbucket, which triggers a new job
- Job from developer B has it's payload overwritten by Developer C payload

  - Job will still shows Develops B name

Even more confusing, if a 4th trigger happens, the 1st job waiting in the queue is lost and all the next ones will be off-by-one.

We have an output configured to display the cause like this:
[image]

And when the issue presents itself I can see on the logs:

```
Bitbucket Build By - Developer 1
Bitbucket Build By - Developer 2
```

This makes me think Jenkins is somehow squashing everything together.

I am trying to find if this is a configuration I can fiddle with, but couldn't find anything so far.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: It does not allow concurrent builds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins Build Queue Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499422/jenkins-build-queue-limit)